# JQuery UI after dragging another element on top make previous go to its original state

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Lets say element r1 is dragged into td1 by mistake, so when I drag r2 element into td1 it should make r1 element go its original position. So basically which one is dragged on top stays in the droppable the other goes back to original state.

Hope that's clear enough.

Any tips would help.

```
$('#r1').draggable({
  revert: true
});
$('#r2').draggable({
  revert: true
});

$('#td1').droppable({
  accept: "#r1,#r2",
  drop: function(e, ui) {
    $(this).html(ui.draggable.remove().html());
    $(this)
      .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this https://plnkr.co/edit/FlxBSsPZovnWyIs9TxXu?p=preview

```
    $(function(){
          var dragid, previd;
         $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
          drag: function(e, ui){
           dragid = $(this).attr('id');
          } 
         });

          $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
              drop: function( event, ui ) {
                  if( $(".droppable").hasClass('hasele')){
                     $('#'+previd).css({'top' : 0, 'left' : 0, 'position': 'relative'});
                  } else{
                    $(".droppable").addClass('hasele');
                    $('#'+dragid).addClass('dropped');
                  }
                  previd = dragid;
              }
            });

        });
```